# What is the simplest way to remove option of select (multiple) when given an array (Pure Javascript only)?

Tags: javascript

Ok, I got

```
<select id="selectUsers" multiple>
<option value="tom">Tom</option>
<option value="mary">Mary</option>
<option value="mike">Mike</option>
<option value="cake">Cake</option>
</select>
```

given `var removeArray=['mary','cake'];`.

After running a `function remove()`, it should be

```
<select id="selectUsers" multiple>
<option value="tom">Tom</option>
<option value="mike">Mike</option>
</select>
```

What is the simplest way to remove option of select (multiple) when given an array (Pure Javascript only)?

Comment: What you have tried for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the elements in the array and use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) in order to select `option` element's with that specific `value` attribute:

```js
var removeArray = ['mary', 'cake'];
var selectElement = document.getElementById('selectUsers');

removeArray.forEach(function(value) {
  var option = selectElement.querySelector('option[value="' + value + '"]');
  if (option) {
    selectElement.removeChild(option);
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="selectUsers" multiple>
  <option value="tom">Tom</option>
  <option value="mary">Mary</option>
  <option value="mike">Mike</option>
  <option value="cake">Cake</option>
</select>
```

If there are multiple elements with the same `value` attribute, you would need to use `.querySelectorAll()` instead of `.querySelector()` and iterate over those option elements:

```js
var removeArray = ['mary', 'cake'];
var selectElement = document.getElementById('selectUsers');

removeArray.forEach(function(value) {
  var options = selectElement.querySelectorAll('option[value="' + value + '"]');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function (option) {
    selectElement.removeChild(option);
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="selectUsers" multiple>
  <option value="tom">Tom</option>
  <option value="mary">Mary</option>
  <option value="mike">Mike</option>
  <option value="cake">Cake</option>
  <option value="cake">Cake</option>
</select>
```

Of course, you could also take the opposite approach and iterate over all the children `option` elements and remove them based on the `value` property:

```js
var removeArray = ['mary', 'cake'];
var selectElement = document.getElementById('selectUsers');

var options = selectElement.querySelectorAll('option');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function(option) {
  if (removeArray.indexOf(option.value) > -1) {
    selectElement.removeChild(option);
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="selectUsers" multiple>
  <option value="tom">Tom</option>
  <option value="mary">Mary</option>
  <option value="mike">Mike</option>
  <option value="cake">Cake</option>
  <option value="cake">Cake</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Tom Yes, it will work in all modern browsers. More specifically, It will work in all browsers that support [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)... in other words, `.querySelector()` is IE8+, and `.forEach()` is IE9+. You could always change the `.forEach` loop to a typical `for` loop, if not it will still work in IE9+.... besides, Microsoft only supports IE11/Edge now anyways.

Comment: Tom, it will in all currently supported browsers (IE11), or if you are concerned about these kinds of problems it might be a good idea to look at jQuery